# How to write annotation outside the drawing in data coords

Tags: python, matplotlib

My graphic goes from `y=-1` to `y=10`

I want to write a small piece of text in an arbitrary position, say at `x=2000`, `y=5`:

```
ax.annotate('MgII', xy=(2000.0, 5.0),  xycoords='data')
```

Now I want the same, but this time the piece of text must be outside the graphic, but in the exact position I mark in data coordinates:

```
ax.annotate('MgII', xy=(2000.0, 10.5),  xycoords='data')
```

But it then disappears (remember my graphic goes from -1 to 10). There is plenty of space free on top of the graphic.

And, if I specify

```
xy=(2000.0, 9.999)
```

then the label appears nearly where I want it, only it is too close to the top border of the picture. I want it at `y=10.5`, specifically.

Comment: @nordev Not convinced that `clip_on` shouldn't  work...the annotation code is a bit finicky (I think it got written first, then artist got re-factored, and annotation never got update)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
ax.annotate('MgII', xy=(2000.0, 10.5), xycoords='data', annotation_clip=False)
```

By default in data units the annotation is only drawn if it is in axes.

You might be better off using a [blended transform](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations):

```
 trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform() # x in data untis, y in axes fraction
 ann = ax.annotate('MgII', xy=(2000, 1.05 ), xycoords=trans)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks very much! (+1) This answer came so quick, that I cannot accept it yet (there is a red warning that says something like: you can accept the answer in 3 minutes). I love StackExchange.

Comment: I see it. Thanks, very useful, even more than the first option.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and found another,very simple solution. Option of the annotate method:

```
annotation_clip=False
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html